# Explicit roots in algebraic extention of Q with roots

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra, computational-number-theory

Denis Bouhineau in "Solving Geometrical Constraint System Using CLP Based on Linear Constraint Solver" gave a method to find explicit square root in algebraic extention of Q with square roots. For example, in the field $Q[\sqrt 2][\sqrt 3]$ the number $5+2\sqrt 6$ has a square root ($\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$), we can find it by this method. He asked "Can this be extended to root of arbitrary degree?" Is this problem solved? I asked Bouhineau, he don't know.